# Clicks between activities-webview when onBackPressed

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have two activities. Both have webView. What I wanted to achieve is to click on the button (located on MainActivity1) automatically when clicking onBackPressed on MainActivity2.

This is my MainActivity2

```
     public void onBackPressed() {
            if (Config.EXIT_APP_BY_BACK_BUTTON_ALWAYS) {
                super.onBackPressed();
}}
```

Is there any possible to put somewhere here an order to click the button like:

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
            if (Config.EXIT_APP_BY_BACK_BUTTON_ALWAYS) {
                super.onBackPressed();
Click --------->>>> button on MainActivity1
}}
```

This is my JS script that webView reading on MainActivity1/webView

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Bounce button
$("#sdf_{$m.blogid}").click(function(){
const element = document.querySelector('#sdf_{$m.blogid}');
element.classList.add('animated', 'bounceIn');
setTimeout(function() {
element.classList.remove('bounceIn');

$('#sdf_{$m.blogid}').load(location.href + " #sdf_{$m.blogid} >*");

}, 1000);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start your MainActivity2 with the result. [StartActivityForResult ALT](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) follow this link. If your MainActivity2 is being started from MainActivity1 then use the above link to start activity and then finish MainActivity2 with a Success result and in MainActivity2 keep listing for Success and when you will have success in MainActivity1 Simply perform whatever method you want to perform

Your **MainActivity1** from where your second activity is being called

```
private fun takeMeToSecondActivityWithResult() {
    startForResultContract.launch(Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java))
}

private val startForResultContract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      
       //Here you will get a callback from MainActivity2 and perform automatic click here
    }
}
```

**MainActivity2** will look like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        //So when it is back press then you listener will get OK Result
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
        super.onBackPressed()
}
```